# SSRS Report - Export to CSV

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I am using ssrs 2005. I have a report with two tables.

**table1**:

```
col11 col12 col13
1     2     3
```

**table2**:

```
col21 col22 col23
a      b     c
d      e     f
g      h     i
```

It renders well on the report, but when I export it to CSV, its bizarre and looks like this:

```
table1,col11,col12,col13,table2,col21,col22,col23 - All the headers on the first line
1,2,3,a,b,c                         - The first row of both tables on the second line
d,e,f                               - The remaining rows of the second table
g,h,i
```

I tried many config/display settings but I cannot get it to work.

I need the csv to be just like the report display:

```
table1,col11,col12,col13 - The headers on the first line
1,2,3                    - The detail rows under the headers
table2,col21,col22,col23 - The second table below the first table
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i
```

I just need the two tables separate in the CSV. Right now the first row of both tables display across and the remaining rows appear below.

Comment: is there a reason why you're exporting to csv from an ssrs report instead of using ssis?

Comment: The task requirements are to deploy the report to Report Server and create a subscription to run the report once a week and send an email with the attachment as csv.

Answer (score 0):

i have seen strange issues with exporting to excel, where it wont put the data in cells correctly, to remedy this I removed all the grouping and floating headers/footers and it worked ok. Might be worth a try?